# CORS issue nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, webpack, cors

We are having 2 domains , Domain A and Domain B. Both domains work well independently. These domains below to React Application developed from Webpack . When we try to access Domain A from Domain B API , we are facing bundle.js file missing. We have included all the appropriate Nginx Conf and Headers. Can someone suggest where we are missing ? React application is dockerized using nginx.

Accessing Domain A from Domain B is not happening.Eventhough we have enabled CORS.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We are using nginx for dockerizing the webpack application

Comment: I will attach the Dockerfile below

Comment: FROM nginx:1.22.1
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN apt-get autoremove
RUN apt-get --purge remove
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get --fix-broken install
RUN apt-get install -y nginx-extras
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY build /var/www/html
RUN cd /var/www/html && mkdir root_folder